# Can functions declared in main access variables declared in main?

Tags: c

I have an array that I declared and initialized in main called Edges.

I have also declared some functions in main that access the array called Edges.

The code compiles and works.

Why does it work? I thought variables declared in main aren't global.

Edit: see Sourav's code.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Show your code. I'm so confused about that function in main.

Comment: The code is over 1100 lines long so I'll give a summary of it

Comment: Okay, I updated it with my code.

Comment: This code even compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if you declare a function inside a function, the inner function is just visible to the outer function and NOT in `global` scope. So, the variables declared by you and the inner function [to be appropriate, the code block] is having same scope. Hence, no issues accessing the variable.

Check this one

## code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int innerfunc();

int main()
{

        int outer = 5;
        int innerfunc()
        {
                printf("outer is %d\n", outer);
        }
        innerfunc();
        return 0;
}
```

## output

```
[sourav@infba01383 so_overflow]# ./a.out 
outer is 5
[sourav@infba01383 so_overflow]#
```

Comment: So any function declared in main can access any variable declared in main?

Comment: @user2108462 get the concept first. . . that inner function cannot be called as a proper `function`. That is a simple `code block`, just as the other lines present in main.

Comment: This is completely misleading. Compile your code with `-pedantic` flag. Nested functions are not allowed in C.

Comment: yer pretty much, as main acts a bit like external container.

but Sourav is correct again, it is simply a block of code, and therefore no need for the whole function declaration

Comment: But I can call the code on itself recursively. And it takes inputs and gives an output. How is it not a function?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I agree that it's a compiler extension, but I compiled the code with `gcc -S` & it did list `.type innerfunc.2680, @function` in assembly, which is _similar_ to what it does for `static functions`
... Note that the function name has been renamed here from `innerfunc` to `innerfunc.2680`, while moving from C to assembly, which is not the case for static functions...

Comment: @haccks Sir, why did you think i was trying to lead to any conclusion regading right or wrong? I was trying to clarify the situation mentioned in the questions. Obviously, some _more strict version_ of the standard does not support this, as i had already mentioned, this is **NOT** a proper `function` anyway. hope this clarify the doubt on my answer.

Comment: @user2108462 ok, no offence, but if i put some kind of `loop` and `goto` statement to achive the same `recursive` behaviour inside some function, will you call that recursive piece of code a seperate function?

Comment: I thought nested functions were a gcc only thing. How is this related to c?

Comment: @Brandin; I still did't understand, how?.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a function inside a function in C. This means that you can't declare  function(s) inside `main`. Compile your code with `-pedantic` flag and you will see this warning for sure;

```
[Warning] ISO C forbids nested functions [-Wpedantic]
```

I compiled this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void void print(int *);

int main()
{
    int a[2] = {1,3};

    void print(int *a)
    {
         printf("%d", *a);
    }
    print(a);
    return 0;
}
```

and getting the warning

```
 [Warning] ISO C forbids nested functions [-Wpedantic]
```

Comment: Then what am I declaring when I declare a function inside main?

Comment: @user2108462 You may be using a compiler which allows you to do that, in which case you'll need to look up its documentation for how that works. (Or tell us what compiler you use so we could do it for you)

Comment: I'm using gcc on linux.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, as most answers have mentioned, it is a gcc extension; not part of standard C.

Below answer is strictly confined to gcc.**

gcc does treat them as any other function.

e.g. Check below code:
(I took liberty to extend your code as below:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int operation(int num1, int num2); // for function pointer...

operation* getOperation(char oper)
{
    int a=10;
    int add(int x, int y){return x+y+a;}
    int sub(int x, int y){return x-y+a;}
    int nop(int x, int y){return a;}

    if(oper=='+')return add;
    if(oper=='-')return sub;
    return nop;
}

int main()
{
    operation *my_op;

    my_op=getOperation('+');
    printf("%d\n",my_op(5,3));

    my_op=getOperation('-');
    printf("%d\n",my_op(5,3));

    return 0;

}
```

If you compile it with `gcc -S` & check the assembly code generated, it would show that

1. The functions - `getOperation` & `main` - are converted to assembly, without any name change. Thus these can be called from any function (in this or even from other file).

   ```
   e.g.
   .globl  getOperation /*This line will be missing in case of static functions.*/
   .type   getOperation, @function
   ```
2. The functions - `add`, `sub`, `nop` - are converted to assembly with some unique random suffix.

   ```
   e.g.
   /*No .globl line is printed here.*/
   .type   add.2685, @function
   ```

Since the names are changed, you cannot call them from other functions. Only the 'parent function' (`getOperation` in this case) has the information of the function name. (Check for `c variable scope` for more details.)

However, you can use them in other functions, using function pointers, as shown in code above.

Regarding the local variables in `getOperation` (`a` for example): They are accessed from `add`/`sub`/`nop` using `rbp` register.
HINT: Compile a small code having 'local functions' with `gcc -S`, to understand what's exactly going on.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nested function (annonymouse functions) are not a part of the c standard library, there is an extension which can be used.

You may declare global variables and use them throughout your programs also.

---

Sourav is correct actually, you may declare the function but its scope is limited to main